# Using query.scrollTo.js with wordpress menu

Tags: jquery

I'm creating my first one page website.

I'm trying to implement scrollTo so that it scrolls nicely to the link, also when it scrolls to the link to change the link colour to let the user know there on that page.

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L4jv29b6/7/

I'm trying to implement it to that I only have 1 trigger rather than a trigger for every single link.

Here's the trigger and this is not even working right see the fiddle:

```
$('#jquery-object').click(function(){
            var $target = $paneTarget.find('li:eq(14)');
            $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo( $target , 800 );
        });
```

I've been stuck on this all day.

Comment: `$paneTarget` is not defined... Did you copy/paste this piece of code from somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/L4jv29b6/8/)

```
$('.scroll').click(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $('body').stop().scrollTo( $target , 800 );
    return false;
});
```

I'll let you handle the overlapping `header` issue.

Edit : for "coloring" the links

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/L4jv29b6/9/)

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

And CSS

```
nav li.active a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Edit 2 : for manual scrolling handling

You could try something like this :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/L4jv29b6/11/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('div[id^="test"]').each(function(i){
        if($(this).position().top < scrollPosition) {
            $('nav li').removeClass('active');
            $('nav li:eq('+i+')').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the scrolling but not the change link colour when on that div.

Comment: Brewal, that is so close to almost perfect, when scrolling manually, it doesn't highlight the text, once it does this it is perfect. Thanks for you help

Comment: That is perfect, i'll mark it as answered and thank you. For bonus points do you know how you can move the page down i.e rather than the h1 title going behind the navigation before the link colour changes, when it goes just under the navigation then the page link changes?